# HTAutocompleteTextField crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to use [HTAutocompleteTextField](https://github.com/hoteltonight/HTAutocompleteTextField) for iOS. I set the text field using the interface builder. Included the required data source and delegate protocols in my header file, and set the datasource/delegate to `self` in my controller. However, as soon as I hit either the call to set the delegate or the datasource the app crashes. I've checked the obvious to make sure I didn't have a `nil` `HTAutocompleteTextField`. Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: Have you set the class of the view in interface builder - in the right hand panel?

Comment: Wow, that is the issue. Very goofy mistake on my part. Could you post that as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Sure! Glad it was something easy. I added a screen shot too for clarity and help in the future! :)

Comment: Cool, thanks! I've had to that that a million times with custom table view cells, you'd think I would have realized I needed it for the textview also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you set the class of the view in Interface Builder to `HTAutocompleteTextField`. This can be done in the right hand side panel.

[image: Right hand side panel]

(Above screen shot is a crop from the official [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles-general/CustomObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009971-CH9-SW1)).